# Can Sequential Quadratic Programming be applied to functions that are non-differentiable on the edge?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $n, m, k \in \mathbb{N}^*$. 
For all $i$ in $1, \cdots, k$, let $A_i$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with non-negative coefficients. 
Let $p$ be a real number greater than $1$.

I want to solve the following minimization problem:
$$\min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i=1}^k \lVert A_i \cdot X \rVert_p$$
subject to the following constraints:
$$\forall 1 \leq j \leq n \colon x_j \in [0, 1] \\ 
\text{and} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j = 1$$

where we denote by $x_j$ the coordinates of $X$, and where $\lVert X \rVert_p$ denotes the $p$-norm of $X$.

As I am simply looking for a way to solve this constrained non-linear optimization problem (locally), and as I am not interested in numerical efficiency, I thought that Sequential Quadratic Programming (SQP) would be an appropriate and simple solution, since my objective fuction is of class $C^2$ almost everywhere.

However, using SQP requires that the objective function (and the constraints) is twice continuously differentiable. 
My problem is that the function $X \mapsto \lVert X \rVert_p$ is not differentiable at the origin, and thus for a given $i$, the function $X \mapsto \lVert A_i \cdot X \rVert_p$ might not be differentiable at some vectors $X$ which contain some zero coordinates (and which would thus be on the edge of the convex set of feasible points).

My question is: is it still mathematically correct to use SQP for my problem even if my objective function is not differentiable for some points on the edge of the feasible set, although being of class $C^2$ on the rest of the set ?